# QT html and CSS to pdf file

Tags: html, css, qt, c++11, pdf

I am using `QTextDocument` and using `setHtml` to add html. Then I used `QPrinter` to print in A4 pdf format `QPrinter::PdfFormat` but the printed pdf did not take the css style sheets. I also tried `QTextDocument::setDefaultHtml` and `setResource`.

The code is as follows. How to get the CSS style in pdf format. 
I use ubuntu and qmake for compiling.

```
const int highQualityDPI = 300;
QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());

QFile  htmlFile ("myhtml.html");
if (!htmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
    return -1;
}

QString htmlContent;
QTextStream in(&htmlFile);
htmlContent=in.readAll();

QFile  cssFile ("style.css");
if (!cssFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
    return -1;
}
QString cssContent;
QTextStream cssIn(&cssFile);
cssContent = cssIn.readAll();

QTextDocument *document = new QTextDocument();
document->addResource( QTextDocument::StyleSheetResource, QUrl( "style.css" ), cssContent );
document->setHtml( htmlContent ); 

QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);

printer.setOutputFileName("output.pdf");

document->print(&printer);
delete document;
return 0;
```

Comment: QTextDocument rendered rich text, not HTML. Supported part of html and css you can see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html).

Comment: For printing html you can use `QWebEngineView::render(QPaintDevice *, const QPoint &, const QRegion &, RenderFlags )`

Comment: Then how to make pdf of html and css file?

Comment: As I say, you can use QWebEngineView. It support html and css.

Comment: I do not think QWebEngineView can be used for printing pdf. Can you show me what print pdf functions help that?

Comment: I am using g++ in the qmake so I do not think QT += webenginewidgets is supported so QWebEngineView is usable in all compiler platforms so can QWebKit be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [QWebEngineView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) & [QWebEnginePage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html)? Just load your HTML file in the WebView and call [printToPdf](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#printToPdf) funciton:

```
 const QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(0,
                                                tr("Save pdf"),
                                                getLastDirectory(),
                                                tr("PDF Files (*.pdf)"));
if (fileName.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}
ui->webView->page()->printToPdf(fileName);
```

To use with QWebKit:

```
    // Set location of resulting PDF
    const QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(0,
                                                tr("Save pdf"),
                                                getLastDirectory(),
                                                tr("PDF Files (*.pdf)"));
    if (fileName.isEmpty()) {
       return;
    } 

    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setOutputFileName(fileName);

    // Create PDF
    ui->webview->print(&printer);
```

How to load the html file with the css? If your HTML links the CSS file correctly in the same folder:

```
QFile  htmlFile ("myhtml.html");
ui->webView->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(htmlFile).absoluteFilePath()));
```

Comment: I am using g++ in the qmake so I do not think QT += webenginewidgets is supported so  QWebEngineView is usable in all compiler platforms so can QWebKit be used?

Comment: I have added some lines showing how to print in the older QWebKit

Comment: But the QWebView  does not give the css feel.

Comment: I have added some lines to show you how to load the html correctly.

Comment: ui->webView->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(file).path());
Multiple problems with this line. First brackets are not correct. Second what is this file variable? 
As I see you use the "myhtml.html" directly right?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't compile the code. It's working fine for me in Qt 5.4 using Ubuntu 14.